# Pandas - General function for checking condition on previous rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I'm writing a function where I'd like to add a series to a dataframe that is `True` if `n` previous rows of another column are negative.

I have this working for a specific number as `n`, but I don't know how to generalize it into a parameter that could be passed in.

For example, we have a dataframe with a column named `Total`. The following code will put `True` in rows in a column titled `consecutive_negative_value` if there are 6 consecutive rows where `Total` is less than zero. How can this be generalized to accept any number `n` instead of just checking six periods?

```
    df['negative_value'] = df['Total'] < 0
    
    df['consecutive_negative_value'] = ( 
        df['negative_value'] &
        df['negative_value'].shift(1) &
        df['negative_value'].shift(2) &
        df['negative_value'].shift(3) &
        df['negative_value'].shift(4) &
        df['negative_value'].shift(5)
    )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `rolling.sum` and check if the sum value is equal to the window size:

```
window = 6
df.Total.lt(0).rolling(window).sum() == window
```

---

*Example* with a window size of 3:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Total': [-1, 2, -2, -2, -3, 2, 3, -1]})

df.Total.lt(0).rolling(3).sum() == 3
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4     True
5    False
6    False
7    False
Name: Total, dtype: bool
```

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate the quick reply :)